# No errors not working two nested for loops in C#

Tags: c#, loops, for-loop

This bugger doesn't work, i cant even check whats wrong because it won't reach the breakpoint. 
If you set a breakpoint at " Console.WriteLine("breakpoint is never reached");" it won't trigger the break.
It's simple code, but i can't figure out why it doesn't work. Probably need more sleep :)
The ThisPixelCheck function, return true or false if a color is found at a point. But it's not reached by the code so it seems.

```
 void FindPixel()
    {
        int x = 455;
        int y = 1109;
        int found = 0;

        Color findcolor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FFFFFF");

        for (int yplus = 0; yplus > 50; yplus++)
        {
            for (int xplus = 0; xplus > 50; xplus++) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("breakpoint is never reached");
                var point = new Point(x + xplus, y + yplus);
                var foundpixel = ThisPixelCheck(point, findcolor);
                if (foundpixel)
                {
                    found += 1;
                }
            }
            status_Label.Text = found.ToString() + " pixels found.";
            }

        }
```

Comment: Given that both yplus and xplus starts at zero the loop conditions are never true. Maybe you meant `for (int yplus = 0; yplus < 50; yplus++)` etc?

Comment: Darnit: i'm going to sleep now, thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

```
void FindPixel()
{
    int x = 455;
    int y = 1109;
    int found = 0;

    Color findcolor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FFFFFF");

    for (int yplus = 0; yplus < 50; yplus++)
    {
        for (int xplus = 0; xplus < 50; xplus++) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("breakpoint is never reached");
            var point = new Point(x + xplus, y + yplus);
            var foundpixel = ThisPixelCheck(point, findcolor);
            if (foundpixel)
            {
                found += 1;
            }
        }
        status_Label.Text = found.ToString() + " pixels found.";
        }

    }
```

the `for` loop is wrong.

Comment: @S.Tacked both.

Comment: Thank you: i wrongfully did a > where it should have been a <. Thank you sir.

Comment: @S.Tacked  pleasure. You can adopt the solution if without no problem :p

Answer (score 0):

```
 for (int yplus = 0; yplus > 50; yplus++)
```

this line yplus is zero and is lower than 50 so programm never goes in the loop.
you should try yplus < 50